# Разработка с открытым исходным кодом

Tags: opensource

Как набрать команду для разработки ПО с открытой лицензией ? Какие языки лучше всего подходят для такой разработки ? Есть ли смысл в определенной операционной системе в такой разработке ? Для себя составил такой перечень языков, подходящих:java, php, python, javascript. Что я не учел ?

Comment: а при чём тут open source и языки? (любой язык подходит, разве что javascript и т.п. сложнее сделать проприетарным)

и как это вы хотите набрать команду под open source, ещё до проработки самой программы и соответственно языка?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы для начала определитесь с тем, что за ПО вообще планируется к созданию, на какую целевую аудиторию рассчитано, предполагается ли получение дохода каким-либо образом и т.п. Ну а если по пунктам:

1. На интересный открытый проект разработчики чуть ли не сами набегут.
2. Язык — любой из распространенных. Точнее вообще любой, но чем он более распространен — тем проще «набрать команду».
3. Смысл в операционной системе есть по определению, выбор целевых ОС — за вами.
4. Вы не учли C, C++, Ruby, Erlang и кучу других языков, но дело не в этом, см. п. 2.

Comment: Какие сферы для новых проектов наиболее интересны разработчикам ?

Comment: @Alex9, ИМХО вы начинаете не с той стороны. Вы собираетесь начать открытый проект, потому что открытая разработка - это модно, это круто (утрирую, конечно), для вас открытая разработка - это самоцель, а должна быть просто одним из способов разработки.

Для начала найдите интересную для **себя** область (а не для сферических в вакууме "открытых" разработчиков), поработайте в ней, пообщайтесь на профильных форумах, когда уже будет что показать - покажите ("во какую крутую штуку делаю, никто не хочет присоединиться?")

Comment: @insolor, вы потрясающе сформулировали то, что и я хотел сказать, но завис над формой изложения.
@Alex9, как это ни странно, разработчикам наиболее интересны <b>интересные</b> проекты. И это в случае вашего вопроса действительно вторично. Придумайте полезную утилиту, изобретите нестандартный подход, да просто решите что-то из востребованного более удобным путем, чем оно решено сейчас. Найдите целевую аудиторию под это, оцените востребованность. И после этого еще раз перечитайте мой ответ и комментарий @insolor.